# Evitar que un script se ejecute segun la resolucion de pantalla ¿es correcto mi codigo?

Tags: javascript

```
if ( window.width > 500 ) {
  //aqui todas las animaciones de mi pagina de tamaño normal (no version movil)    
}
```

Con el codigo de arriba pretendo que todas las animaciones de mi pagina y en general scipts esten habilitados solo cuando la resolucion de pantalla sea mayor a 500px, es decir, quiero que mi pagina tenga dos scrips separados, uno para mi web tamaño normal (para laptops, pc de escritorio, tablets) y el otro para mi sitio en tamaño móvil (las resoluciones menores de 500px trabajaran con otro script)...

He probado el codigo de arriba y funciona. Cuando mi navegador tiene el tamaño normal ejecuta correctamente todas las animaciones, pero cuando reduzco al tamaño a 500 o menos ya no funcionan..El unico problema es que se necesita cargar la pagina, porque de lo contrario no se actualiza el script.. O sea, cuando reduzco la ventana a 500, para que funcione el condicional debo actualizar la pagina..Si usara ajax se actualizaria sin necesidad de cargar, pero por ahora no domino esa tecnologia. Igual supongo que este inconveniente no es gran problema, porque yo no espero que la persona redimencione su ventana, sino que ingrese con una resolucion ya establecida, y al cargar la pagina el condicional detecte si debe o no ejecutar las animaciones.

Bien, ahora quiero preguntar si es que meter tooodo mi codigo (que es mediano, son 5 animaciones) dentro del condicional ¿no hara la pagina mas lenta? (o no tiene nada que ver??)..y segundo: si alguien tiene una mejor forma de hacer lo que yo estoy intentando, por favor que me la diga......gracias.

Comment: puedes utilizar @media query para la resolución de pantalla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/resolution

Answer (score 1):

**Duda 1**

> El unico problema es que se necesita cargar la pagina, porque de lo contrario no se actualiza el script.. O sea, cuando reduzco la ventana a 500, para que funcione el condicional debo actualizar la pagina

Efectivamante, si el condicional se evalua al cargar la página, no volverá a evaluarse hasta recargarla. Si quieres forzar que vuelva a evaluarse puedes ponerle un listener al objeto `window` que se gatille cuando la pantalla sea redimensionada.

```
window.addEventListener('resize',function() { 
  miFuncion(); 
});
```

Ahora, tienes que pensar bien qué quieres que ocurra cuando llamas a `miFuncion` o, mejor dicho, pensar tu página para que las animaciones no dependan de la resolución inicial sino de la resolución actual luego de un redimensionamiento.

Por otro lado, dada tu suposición:

> yo no espero que la persona redimencione su ventana, sino que ingrese con una resolucion ya establecida

Podríamos decir que en realidad no necesitas ayuda o bien no está claro lo que se pregunta.

---

**Duda 2**

> meter tooodo mi codigo (que es > mediano, son 5 animaciones) dentro del condicional ¿no hara la pagina > mas lenta? (o no tiene nada que ver??)

Si te refieres a que la versión móvil cargará un segmento de texto inactivo sin propósito, será menos que óptimo pero no se notará.

---

**Duda 3**

> si alguien tiene una mejor forma de hacer lo que yo estoy intentando,
>   por favor que me la diga

Para efectos de lo que quieres, en vez de mi sugerencia de arriba tendría más sentido reconsiderar tu flujo actual:

```
if(window.width > 500 ) {
   function animacion1() {
     ...
   }

   function animacion2() {
     ...
   }

   function animacion3() {
     ...
   }
}
```

Y reescribirlo como

```
function animacion1() {
  if (window.width <= 500) {
    return false;
  }
  //... código
}

function animacion2() {
  if (window.width <= 500) {
    return false;
  }
  //... código
}

function animacion3() {
  if (window.width <= 500) {
    return false;
  }
  //... código
}
```

De manera que no exista el flujo de "apagar" o "encender" las animaciones (que en este caso estarían -me imagino- asociadas a ciertos listeners), sino que cada una se cortocircuite si detecta una resolución móvil.

**Otra idea:**

Por otro lado, también tienes que plantearte si acaso es necesario usar javascript para la animación. Gran parte de lo que requería JS hace años hoy se puede hacer con CSS, y usando media queries puedes hacer que ciertos comportamientos CSS se apliquen sólo en ciertas resoluciones sin detectar un evento `resize`. Básicamente  serían animaciones responsivas.

Por ejemplo:

- Mediante un **listener** manejo que al pinchar una opción del menú superior se despliege un colapsable

  - Con javascript: el handler manipula la posición del colapsable y su visibilidad. **Si la resolución es menor a 500** no hay un movimiento sino que sólo aparece
  - Con CSS: el handler sólo añade o quita una clase, el estilo que se aplica maneja la animación nativamente. Con un media query controlo si quiero que haya un movimiento fluido o instantáneo. **Si la resolución es menor a 500**, al JS le da lo mismo: ese es problema del CSS.

Otro ejemplo:

- Al pasar el mouse sobre un ícono, quiero que se despliegue un tooltip

  - con JS: añado un listener al evento `mouseOver` y manipulo el DOM alterando la visibilidad del tooltip. **Si la resolución es menor a 500**, retorno false y no hay tooltip.
  - Con CSS: uso el seudoselector `:hover` para modificar el comportamiento (y visibilidad) de los nodos que son hijos del elemento (y en este caso, el tooltip debiera ser hijo del elemento). Si la resolución es menor a 500 puedo inhibir ese comportamiento con un media query.

En resumen, hay animaciones que requieren JS necesariamente para añadir un listener. Te diría que salvo añadir o quitar clases, ese listener no debiera tocar el DOM para añadir transiciones ni animaciones.

Comment: Hola. Java Script sigue siendo necesario para las animaciones porque con CSS3 no puedes acceder al DOM ni usar EVENTOS.. Media Queries tambien uso, pero para este aso no me sirve porque no la puedo mezclar con Java Script. Y sobre tu primer ejemplo, no resulta conveniente porque el usuario que accesa a mi web no va a redimencionar la ventana de su navegador, y por ende, el evento no se disparará

Comment: No especificaste el tipo de animaciones. Por eso dije: "Tienes que plantearte si es necesario". ¿Es necesario? Ok, no tienes que convencerme a mí, es decisión tuya. Un listener podría añadir o quitar una clase que a su vez generara una transición o animación, era sólo una sugerencia. Voy a editar mi respuesta para clarificar